# Как подогнать изображение внутри блока по высоте?

Tags: html, css

Вывожу изображения динамически в карусель. Как сделать чтоб изображение любой высоты подгонялось под размер блока по высоте, как сделано на скриншоте ниже?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите свой код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предложил другой вариант, т.к. пропорции могут быть разные и чтобы с этим не замарачиваться создаем div и привязываем background

```html
<div style="background: url(http://vialan.com.ua/img/vialan.png) center; background-size: cover; height: 100px;  width: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: не лучший вариант.  ковер не всегда хорошо отрабатывает. во-первых может обрезать картинку, во-вторых потянуть.

Comment: Согласен, но тут задача заполнить указанный блок картинкой, иначе будут искажения.

Comment: Вообще правильное решение. и высоту и ширину задать авто с заданием максимальной ширины и высоты 100% что бы не вылазили больше.. и будет выводиться картинка оригинального размера но не больше границ экрана. а если картинка маленькая то для этого есть бекэнд который и должен те самые картинки при заливке резать ан разные размеры.

Comment: :) Думаю если человек спрашивает о том как правильно картинку отобразить, то нагружать его бекэнд обработкой это уже будет лишнее. А вот cover отрабатывает для меня на 100.

Comment: Довольно корректно отображается, за исключением того, что у высоких изображений показывается только середина. Что подскажете? <div style="background: url(http://test1.ru/admin/files/places/{{img1.img}}) center; background-size: cover; height: 300px;  width: auto"></div>

Comment: Я так понимаю середина отображается только на слишком широких, об этом и говорил Maxim, но изображение либо будет терять пропорции либо показывать только центра, можно поиграть с bagckroud-position, это в кроткой надписи center, тогда будет показывать верх или любую указанную сторону

Comment: Да и еще позиционирование можно указывать с привязкой к двум краям rigth bottom

Answer (score 3):

Даете картинке какой то класс к примеру

```
<img class="slider-image" src='#'>
```

И стиль

```
.slider-image{
   height:100%;
   width: auto;
}
```

При этом картинка растянется на высоту блока родителя, проследите что бы высота блока родителя была тоже 100% (не была фиксированной)

Если дать класс картинке не можете то дайте его блоку родителю

```
<div class="slider-image">
   <img src='#'>
</div>
```

И стиль

```
.slider-image img{
   height:100%;
   width: auto;
}
```

Должно сработать если у вас не перебивается никакими другими стилями, по этому лучше было бы выложить ваш код.

вариант с бекграундом

```
img{
    background-image: url(http://vialan.com.ua/img/vialan.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

дал ширину и высоту равную размеру экрана, а свойство контейн - заполняет картинкой.

Comment: <div style="height: 300px;">
                <img ng-src="http://test1.ru/admin/files/places/{{img1.img}}" style="height:100%;
   width: auto;">
              </div>

Comment: Но, изображение не масштабируется, если изменять ширину браузера

Comment: вас не смущает <div style="height: 300px;"> ? то есть вы уже дали высоту 300 и хотите что бы было больше заданной? и не используйте инлайн стилей!!! неужели так сложно дать класс, и вынести стили в файл? потом же сами будете мучатся в попытке перебить стили или вообще в итоге прочитать код шаблона загаженный данным делом.

Comment: что сделать чтобы картинка по ширине вписывалась в края браузера? а та, что высокая - вписывалась по высоте? простите за грамматику

Comment: растягивалась или не вылазила за края?

Comment: если что бы не вылазила то max-width; max-height

Comment: Делаю вот так, не работает: <div style="height: 300px;">
                <img ng-src="http://test1.ru/admin/files/places/{{img1.img}}" style="height:100%;
   width: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%">
              </div>

Comment: а растягивать. просто так у вас не получится. либо скрипт писать который будет распознавать какого рода это картинка и применять тот или иной стиль.  либо как вариант пробовать как ниже предложено бегкранд ковер. ну или еще думать варианты. есть еще но не могу вспомнить. немного занят.

Comment: добавил вариант, как по мне лучше чем cover